# Cabal-install error: /usr/bin/ld cannot find -lHSparsec-3.1.7-ghc7.8.3

Tags: ghc, cabal, cabal-install

I have an old version of cabal-install so I downloaded cabal-install 1.20 and When installing it errors out.

Additional note: ghc 7.8.3
OS: CentOS 6.6

Error:

```
Building network-2.4.2.3...
.......
......
......
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSparsec-3.1.7-ghc7.8.3
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error during cabal-install bootstrap:
building the network package failed.
```

When I try to run "cabal install network-2.5.0.0",getting following errors

```
root@gains: cabal install network-2.5.0.0
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring network-2.5.0.0...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/tmp/network-2.5.0.023068/network-2.5.0.0':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
network-2.5.0.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error :

```
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/tmp/network-2.5.0.023068/network-2.5.0.0':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

So, I run command `yum groupinstall "development tools"`, installed c compiler tools and could compile c programs. Then,

```
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in /tmp/network-2.5.0.023068/network-2.5.0.0':
```

I tried `mount -o remount,exec,suid /tmp` which solved the error.Its because of execution rights issue on the file system.